# What happens when I save changes to web.config with a live app?

Tags: .net, web-config

What happens when I save a change to web.config while the application is live? The reason I ask is that I'm working on a site/webapp right now which is built on top of an e-commerce platform. At seemingly random intervals, the site will stop responding. The process for the app pool is normal (no ridiculous memory or CPU usage when this happens). When I make a small change to web.config--such as adding a space or deleting a space, and then saving--the site seems to come back. I think by learning more about the sequence of events AFTER the save, I can narrow down the potential causes of my problem.

Edit: I should mention we're running on IIS 6.

Comment: Is the question - "Why does the AppPool recycle after I save the Web.Config?"  Or, is it - "My web app stops responding for an unknown reason, but recycling the AppPool fixes it.  How do I diagnose?"

Comment: The question is, "What happens when I save web.config?" Is the answer, "The AppPool is recycled?" I don't know if that's the case unless the process ID for the AppPool somehow remains unchanged.

Comment: Yes, the AppDomain is recycled. config files are only read once per AppDomain. Recycling the AppDomain is necessary to cause the changes in the config file to take effect.

Comment: Well, partially it depends on how the AppPool is configured.  But, generally, when you deploy new content to a Web App in IIS, the application will restart.  Changing the Web.Config counts as "deploying new content."

Comment: Hm, okay. I'm afraid whatever it is, it's inside the code for the e-commerce platform--which of course is not open source, so I can't do anything about it. Anyway, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Jacob: this is not true. When you deploy new content, the AppDomain will not restart - unless that new content includes a new web.config, or changes the contents of the bin folder.

Comment: @John: Thank you for the clarification.  I didn't realize it was only assemblies or web.config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The AppDomain it's running on ceases to take new work, and a new one is started.

Comment: So you think perhaps something in the AppDomain is causing the site to become unresponsive? I'm just wondering why I'm seeing no high CPU usage or memory usage, yet the site won't respond at all until a change is made to web.config.

Comment: "Something in the AppDomain" - _everything_ is in the AppDomain. All the code. All the data. So, yes, "something in the AppDomain" is breaking.

Comment: I'd say that if recycling the appdomain fixes your app, something in your app is getting hung up or not responding.